# SQL Server 2012 Express login failed from client machine

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I have installed SQL Server 2012 Express edition on a pc which is on a workgroup running Windows 10. I have also created an user for access to the database through the VS2013 application.

When trying to connect to the server from the client machine, I am getting a message saying login failed and it is from an untrusted domain. The client is also on the same workgroup. However, after the SQL Express was installed on the "server" machine, the name of that pc was changed. I can connect to the database from the server using SSMS using the new computer name (in the instance). I have set remote connection parameters and also configured firewall rules. Yet I am unable to access the server from the client machine.

I also want to ensure that the database is totally secured against access or intrusion. Anyone having access to the server machine can view/edit the database using Windows Authentication. How best to safeguard against it?

Any tips would be appreciated.

CL

Answer (score 0):

try to make a new user in server machin using SSMS and be sure that you are adding the new user to the Login Part of Security in SSMS . For this you need to Login to SSMS as administrator ...

Comment: Thank, I tried but i am still getting the same message even if i use the new user credentials